# Prove that $\sigma_T(T_1,T_2)\subset\sigma(T_1)\times\sigma(T_2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $(T_1,T_2)$ be a pair of commuting operators acting on $\mathcal{H}$. $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in \sigma_T(T_1,T_2)$ if and only if the Koszul-Complex of $(T_1-\lambda_1,T_2-\lambda_2)$ is not exact. This is equivalent that at least one of the following properties fails:

- $(a)$ The equation system
  $$(T_1-\lambda_1)\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=0\;\; \wedge \;\; (T_2-\lambda_2)\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=0$$
  has the unique solution $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$.
- $(b)$ The only solutions for the equation
  $$(T_1-\lambda_1)\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}+(T_2-\lambda_2)\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}=0$$
  are of the form
  $$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=-(T_2-\lambda_2)\begin{pmatrix} s_1 \\ s_2 \end{pmatrix}\;\;\text{and}\;\;\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}=(T_1-\lambda_1)\begin{pmatrix} s_1 \\ s_2 \end{pmatrix},$$
  for some $(s_1,s_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2$.
- $(c)$ The equation
  $$(T_1-\lambda_1)\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}+(T_2-\lambda_2)\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix},$$
  has a solution for every $(b_1,b_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2$.

> I want to prove that 
>   $$\sigma_T(T_1,T_2)\subset\sigma(T_1)\times\sigma(T_2)$$

For more informations about the Taylor spectrum see:

J. L. Taylor, A joint spectrum for several commuting operators, J. Functional Anal. 6(1970), 172-191.

we have

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that $\mathcal H=\mathbb C^2$. There is no need for that.

Take $(\lambda,\mu)$ such that at least $\lambda\not\in\sigma(T_1)$ or $\mu\not\in\sigma(T_2)$. Suppose first that $\lambda\not\in\sigma(T_1)$ (the other case is similar). So $T_1-\lambda I$ is invertible. For typing simplicity, from now on I will write $T_1$ instead of $T_1-\lambda I$, and $T_2$ instead of $T_2-\mu I$.

As $T_1$ is invertible,  $\ker T_1=\{0\}$, so 
$$\tag1
\ker T_1\cap \ker T_2=\{0\}. 
$$
For the second condition, if $T_1x+T_2y=0$, then $x=-T_1^{-1}T_2y=T_2T_1^{-1}y$. Let $z=T_1^{-1}y$. Then 
$$\tag2
x=-T_2z,\ \ \ y=T_1z,
$$
so the second condition is satisfied.

Finally, since $T_1$ is onto, the sum of the images of $T_1$ and $T_2$ is $\mathcal H$. Together with $(1)$ and $(2)$, this shows that if $(\lambda,\mu)\not\in\sigma(T_1)\times\sigma(T_2)$, then $(\lambda,\mu)\not\in\sigma_T(T_1,T_2)$. Thus
$$
\sigma_T(T_1,T_2)\subset\sigma(T_1)\times \sigma(T_2). 
$$

Comment: If $\mathcal H$ is not $\mathbb{C}^2$ the inclusion is not in general true? Also I don't see where exactely you use the fact that $\mathcal H =\mathbb{C}^2$? Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the paper of Taylor $X$ is a Banach space.

Comment: Did you read my answer? In your question, you used $\mathcal H=\mathbb C^2$; in my answer, I'm saying that such a thing is not necessary.

Comment: Now I understand. Yes in my question I use $\mathbb{C}^2$ in order to understand with an example.

Comment: I don't really know what $\sigma_T(\mathbf T)$ is. I would still expect the same argument to work, though.

Comment: I actually just noticed that you have a typo in (2): You are writing T_1 and T_2 and not $(T_1 - \lambda)$ and $(T_2 - \mu)$. The proof still works, of course! Also in line 3, we have $T_1$ and not $T$. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. In these arguments one usually works with $\lambda=0$ because it is possible to translate. I wrote half my answer like that. I'll edit.